# Tawk.to (free live chat script) produces 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, .htaccess, header, tawk.to

I installed a free live chat from tawk.to. The problem (besides they not having a customer support for this script) is - it produces '400 Bad Request' error when it connects to the tawk.to servers. I added the below codes to .htaccess to allow different origins, but they don't work - the 400 error still appears. I don't know what else should be done.

I tried these in .htaccess without success:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.tawk\.to)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.tawk.to
```

The response header (assuming I put this script on EXAMPLE.com):

```
Accepttext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8Accept-Encodinggzip, deflate, brAccept-Languageen-US,en;q=0.5Cache-Controlno-cacheConnectionkeep-alive, UpgradeCookie__tawkuuid=e::tawk.to::CZ4miEdTw+LJy27l6cezd/vgJ1Go/uVCmU/4mrr+WIe5uNur3LjRp6TAhWSTCS83::2; __cfduid=d8cf244362c2ead0f846b52cd84058bd31488522157DNT1

Host vs51.tawk.to

Origin https://EXAMPLE.com

Pragmano-cacheSec-WebSocket-Extensionspermessage-deflateSec-WebSocket-KeyBPkRsxjD+iWVmfb3LV8zpA==Sec-WebSocket-Version13UpgradewebsocketUser-AgentMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
```

The Error Response:

```
GET https://vs51.tawk.to/s/ [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 162ms]
```

Here is an example Javascript from tawk.to (note it contains the 'crossorigin"* attribute but it still produces the error):

```
<!--Start of Tawkto (example)-->
<script>
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/0111111111/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawkto-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update - contacting support@tawk.to doesn't work (no response). But I did more research - I found a few sites that use tawk.to chat and the 400 Bad Request error appears on these sites too.. so it must be something inherent/buggy to tawk.to script which for now is not resolved and all their customers are affected.

Comment: we too have the same issue still now, I think this will only work on https domains. I would like to know, if you got your issue resolved. But my error is related to CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: In my example I use https and the warnings still appear (no response from the support either).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are blocking specific countries in your tawkto account widget. Please try disabling country blocking on your widget. It works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but I got it resolved.
The things you need to account for are the following:

- You need to supply a userId with the call
- Hash should be lower case of the userId and the Api Key

Here's a work sample code: (Please note this is not runnable code, you will need to add your own variables for it to work, but i'm able to get my users to login now)

```js
var isLoggedIn = false;
var Tawk_API = {
  onLoad: function() {
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      isLoggedIn = true;
      window.Tawk_API.login({
        hash: '{{Put your Hash here}}',
        name: '{{ User Name}}',
        email: '{{ User Email }}',
        userId: '{{ User ID }}'
      }, function(error) {
        //do something if there's an error
      });
    }
  }
};
var Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
(function() {
  var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
    s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s1.async = true;
  s1.src = '{{ Put your Chat Link here }}';
  s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
  s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
  s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
})();
```